# Setting environment variable using shell script

Tags: scripting, environment-variables, csh

I am using csh scripts for some automation purpose. I have a number of scripts, and the beginning of all of which I need to set a fixed set of environment variables.

```
|----SCRIPT 1---|     |----SCRIPT 2---|
|# set env vars |     |# set env vars |
|               |     |               |
|# do something |     |# do something |
|               |     |# else         |
```

So I thought that I'll put all the environment variables in another script and source it from each file. But as it turns out, environment variables set inside the sourced script are not reflected outside. Is there any clean way to achieve what I want? Or do I have to explicitly set environment variables in each script ?

**UPDATE :**

While sourcing the file, I was piping the output to a file using the 'tee' command. I noticed that after removing the pipe, the script file worked.

Comment: If you use `source` then it should work. If you actually *execute* the script it doesn't because that's a different process. What *exactly* did you do?

Comment: I sourced the script.

Comment: You should post a minimal example that demonstrates the problem; because right now we can only guess as to where your error is...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, piping the output of `source` will run that part of the pipeline in a subshell, which means that any environment variables set by the sourcing of the other file will not affect the script's environment.

Example:

`environment.csh`:

```
setenv string "hello world"
echo 'The environment is now set up'
```

`script.csh`:

```
#!/bin/csh

source environment.csh | tee output
printf 'string is "%s"\n' "$string"
```

The output of running `script.csh` will be

```
The environment is now set up
string: Undefined variable.
```

Removing the pipe to `tee` will make it output

```
The environment is now set up
string is "hello world"
```